# How to distinguish between ACTION_UP and actual click via onTouchListener?

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

I have an `ImageView` with an icon. I want to be able to:
**1**. Change the icon on hover (meaning - change to icon #2 on **ACTION_DOWN** but also change it back to icon #1 on **ACTION_UP**)
**2**. Trigger an onClick function (meaning - call another function when the `ImageView` was **clicked**)

This is how my `onTouch` looks like right now:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            // CHANGE TO IMAGE #2
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            // CHANGE TO IMAGE #1
            break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

The problem is - I can't know when the user pressed my `ImageView` and then left its area *while still pressing down*. I hope I explaied it well. I mean that **ACTION_UP** does not always imply that the user intended to **click** the View. How can I know for sure when the `ImageView` was **clicked** and not just hovered (and still be able to change the icon on hover)?

Comment: well i think you want [selector](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-imagebutton-selector-example/) for your image

Comment: @Nowshad Yes, great. Thank you for this comment

Comment: if you have problem in handling the onclick event try to do setOnLongClickListener.Check if you are still facing the similar problem or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Selector Drawable` Something Like This.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- default -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_bg" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" />

    <!-- button focused -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_bg_focus_new" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" />

    <!-- button pressed -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_bg_focus_new" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 1):

Will be better if you'll use **selector**. You can read more about [StateList](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList). There are many examples in Internet how it use.

Comment: So simple. Thank you!